# How to write the query function for checking duplicate registereD in Appwrite using Flutter

Tags: flutter, appwrite

I'm a new intern at this small tech company that uses appwrite as a database for developing mobile applications using flutter. The task was to check if there are duplicate registration IDs in Appwrite database and, if there are, notify users that the ID already exists and ask them to enter a different registration ID when completing their user profile. The query function for checking duplicate IDs is proving to be a challenge for me because I'm a newbie to flutter and appwrite.

It first checks whether the registryID parameter is successfully received, and returns the registration ID under the registryID column in the Appwrite document, but when printing out the result, it returns an empty map. So I believe I somehow wrote the function incorrectly.

```
Future<dynamic> checkDuplicateID(String registerID) async{
try {
  dynamic res =  await db.listDocuments(
      collectionId: kycCollectionId,
  queries: [
    Query.equal('registryId', registerID),
  ]
  );
} on AppwriteException catch(e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
}
```

here is the appwrite image that contains document information and registryID row[image]

In submit button section where the user submits her information, I used a provider package and called the checkDuplicateID method and passed the id "UKH00250238", which is repeated twice in the database.

```
onTap: () {
dynamic result = state.checkDuplicateID('UKH00250238');

}
```

If the above function is incorrect, how do I write a function in which I can pass a registerID as a parameter and check if the id is already repeated? If my implementation is incorrect, what are the other ways to check duplicate IDs in the Appwrite?

Comment: It's fine to ask questions here, but note that if you are an intern (or a junior) then someone should be looking after you at your place of work. Unfortunately many companies are just dreadful at providing sufficient support for new software engineers. Do you have staff in your department that you can freely ask questions to without judgement?

Comment: If you are under pressure to deliver work ("needs to be done ASAP") then it may be that your employer does not know how to treat interns properly (other than using them as a source of inexpensive labour). I appreciate you can't do a lot about it, but I mention it to adjust your expectations of what a good internship looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkDuplicateID()` function should probably return something to indicate whether there's a duplicate or not. Otherwise, the function seems fine, assuming the user has access to the data.

Your next step is probably to have some sort of UI to collect input from the user so that you can pass it into your `checkDuplicateID()` function. The Flutter Docs have plenty of resources you can use, like [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input).

If you still need help from the Appwrite size, feel free to join the [Appwrite Discord server](https://appwrite.io/discord).